# make Footer template visible and invisible in button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, footer

I have a grid with footer template. It consists of a text box in which i will add some value and after clicking btnAdd the value present in the footer template will append to the main grid. Below is my footer template. I want to make the footer template visible only on clicking btnAdd. How to make it visible and invisible on some button click.
Note: button located outside grid.

```
<FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFactor" Style="margin-left: 210px" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server"  >
                        </asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to rebind your datasource after setting the ShowFooter = true.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `GridView.ShowFooter = IsInEditMode` from codebehind on button-click.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showfooter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
GridView1.ShowFooter = false;
```

Comment: by default footer will be false or true?

Comment: Yup by default it is false.You make it true or false as you want on buttton click event!